# Не отрабатывает корректно push

Tags: java, eclipse, github, git-bash

Привет. Такая проблема. Немножко не корректно в начале добавил в репозиторий папку из другого репозитория(забыл удалить мето-папку .git), сделал **add .** , **commit**, **push**.
Всё как-то залилось на GitHub. Но с веб интерфейса в папку не зайти, а на **pull** на другом ПК скачиваться просто пустая папка.

[image: Проблема в Tasks]

После исправления в основном локальном репозитории, не отрабатывает push.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 36, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 11.71 KiB | 1.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 36 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object aaa8ce61733a20e8bc12913076e1c949131728c3: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
remote: fatal: Error in object
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

Что нужно ещё исправить?

Дополнение:
При выполнении команды:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Task/*" HEAD
```

Выдаёт:

```
error: invalid object 160000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for 'Tasks'
warning: cache entry has null sha1: Tasks
error: invalid object 160000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for 'Tasks'
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
fatal: Not a valid object name
could not write rewritten commit
```

Ссылка [на репозиторий на github'e](http://github.com/IlyaBeetle/AcademicWorkspace)

Comment: Я просто удалить файлы с гитхаба (в вебинтерфейсе) и потом заново склонировать репозиторий не получается?

Comment: Ок. Как это сделать? Мне не известны способы удаления файлов не из командной строки. И я не уверен, что косяк в файле на сервере.

Comment: Заходите по вебу на страницу файла на github'е и там правом верхнем углу будет знак корзины  (рядом с чем-то вроде: 12 lines (9 sloc) | 922 Bytes | Raw | Blame | History), цифры, конечно будут другими,

Comment: Я не могу зайти как в файл.

Comment: а киньте тогда ссылку, если у вас открытый репозиторий

Comment: https://github.com/IlyaBeetle/AcademicWorkspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно откатить последний коммит, это делается с помощью

```
git revert номер-коммита
```

Я сделал [pull request](https://github.com/IlyaBeetle/AcademicWorkspace/pull/5) в ваш репозиторий с откатом вашего последнего коммита, сохраните измененные файлы c последнего коммита, примите мой pull request, а потом заново залейте уже без проблемной директории. Либо можете сами сделать откат в вашем локальном репозитории:

```
git revert 9b32296f77d7b7d83491031609dc275da9ca19d4
```

После этого push должен ходить нормально.